# best way to implement laravel database system to manage posts read/share/edit permissions

Tags: database, laravel, data-structures, package, access-rights

Thank you for helping on this!
I am designing an app with documents and posts sharing with Laravel.
I tried to do it myself since two weeks but I am not sure what the best is.
I've tried implementing many packages and used crud generators, but as a Laravel beginner it's difficult to find the good package and to mix them.
What I want is a system like google docs sharing behaviour but for posts.
You could write a post and set it as

- private
- shared with those with the secret link
- shared with users names list (or ids in database)
- shared with groups of users

So what is the best way to build that?

- 1) Using a package? Which one?
- 2) table_users | table_posts | table_permissions

  - one permission per user that can read / edit (permission level)
- 3) table_users | table_posts including permissions for each posts

  - owner_id
  - share_link
  - users_that_can_read
  - users_that_can_edit

If anyone can direct me to a good tutorial or give me a good start structure for this tables to be efficient and secure.

Maybe I do not see all the complexity of this so I will enjoy any suggestions
The problem for this is I want a more flexible rights management than wordpress one that provides user rights levels, the availability of data will be managed by simple subscribers for a lot of things(files, posts, maybe comments, groups and maybe more stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create three tables `roles`,`permissions` and `roles_permission`.The roles of the user goes in the table `roles` table.the permission of a user are stored in the table `permission`.You can map the roles and permission of a particular user in the `roles_permission` table.However,for more flexible way to add role-based-permission use [entrust](https://packagist.org/packages/zizaco/entrust) package.In which,you can dynamically add/update/delete the roles and permissions in laravel.

Comment: But will this permit a user to say for exemple only greg, max and john and my bicycle group can read this post?

Comment: Yes, you can assign permission to individual and group as well.

Comment: I'm not sure the question was understood...
I am not trying to give **admin** role or **visitor** role, or **editor** role  I am trying to give to the posts i.e. id=87 from user i.e. id=32 private access by this user, not by admin user, and for this particular user the ability to say that users ids=[34,57,128] and groups ids=[13,28,...] can read, and users or groups ids[...] can contribute, and users or groups ids[...] can comment, etc...  
And all what I get on google or entrust package doc is about users roles like admin and so on